# Make SonarQube (Android Lint profile) use the project's lint.xml

Tags: android, sonarqube, lint

I analyzed my Android project with SonarQube (Android Lint profile).
By default, Lint shows missing translations as Critical, but I consider them a minor problem.

So I wrote this `lint.xml` file in the project's home (same folder as `sonar-properties.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lint>
    <issue id="MissingTranslation">
        <ignore path="res/values/constants.xml" />
    </issue>
</lint>
```

Unfortunately, SonarQube does not seem to take this file into account.
How to make SonarQube use my `lint.xml`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like for every language plugin that offers rules in SonarQube, you should [customize those rules](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Configuring+Rules) (severity, parameters) your quality profile in SonarQube itself - not in a file that belongs to your project.

So in your case, you have to go on the quality profile used for your project, find the rule that creates issues for missing translations, and change its severity to minor.

Comment: Will the Android Lint Plugin only take issues from the lint result file into account or run again over the code with all rules from the Quality Profile? Then what is the purpose of passing the lint results file?

Answer (score 1):

@Fabrice - SonarSource Team

I have a different opinion.
In my case I tried to ignore the lint error unused resources.
So I configured the file *lint.xml* like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lint>
    <issue id="UnusedResources" severity="ignore"/>
</lint>
```

After that I ran `./gradlew lint` to generate the Lint report and hosted the report in sonarqube server using `./gradlew sonarqube`.

As a fact the Lint report does not contain the *unusedresources* error and
does not show up on SonarQube server even though the rule is still active in my quality profile.

So according to me in this way we can make SonarQube use *lint.xml*.